# Application not searching on play store with app Google play application english title

Tags: android, search, localization, google-play, publish

I had published an application with title with both english and hindi keywords eg. Consider my app name is "Ajay", then i have added app name in playstore as "Ajay अजय". (I am not sharing actual app name for client privacy reason)

I am able to look for application in Google play store by its hindi name "अजय" but the application is not found in play store by english application title "Ajay".

I have already added short and long description for the application ib both hindi and english and have tried adding the word "Ajay" in description also so that my application gets searched with english name as well. But still it is not searchable by english name "Ajay" in google playstore.

What could be going wrong and How can it be rectified?
Any help would be appreciated.. !!!

Comment: why not contact support?

Comment: did you see all the pages in search? My app was in 10th page. try looking at other pages as well

Comment: Yes i had searched all pages earlier. But app was not listed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had mentioned the application details in long description using application English title. Initially the application was not occurring in playstore, i had searched all apps which were filtered out by my application title. However after some downloads and obtaining ratings from few users the application was getting searched in playstore with English keyword too. Another reason may be playstore seo takes few days to add app in filtered search list. My app is coming in first position now reason being the application name is unique name.

Answer (score 4):

Google Play search is a key tool for users to find relevant, and popular apps for Android devices. Ensuring that your app and store listing is thorough and optimized is an important factor in getting discovered by users on Google Play.

You can follow these steps to optimize your app.

https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/4448378?hl=en

Also, google take some time to index your app in the search result. SO always use some unique name otherwise google will take much time based on your application  traffic, rating and keywords.